# Regular expression to get the value between HTML tags

Tags: .net

I need to extract the value between html tags. So I guess I need to make use of some regular expression. My input is:

```
<th style="text-align: left; padding: 4px 8px; margin-bottom: 0px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;">Monitoring Parameter</th>
```

Expected output: `Monitoring Parameter`

Unfortunately my pattern `"<th[^>]*>(.*?)</th>"` does not work.

Thanks In advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Mathyn's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56236818/regular-expression-to-get-the-value-between-html-tags#comment99092385_56236818), Regex and HTML don't go well together.

If you want to work with HTML in C# I would recommend [HTML Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/), which lets you parse HTML and use LINQ to navigate through it. It can be a bit daunting when starting off, but you'll have a much better time than trying to handle the irregularities of HTML with Regex.